# this.constructor.SomeVarible vs this.SomeVarible in OOP JS

Tags: javascript, oop, constructor

So what is the difference between the following 2 examples?

```
var SomeFn = function (name){this.constructor.SomeVarible = name}
```

And

```
var SomeFn = function (name){this.SomeVarible = name}
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have

```
var obj = new SomeFn('foo');
```

In the first case, the value will be assigned to `SomeFn.SomeVarible`, since `this.constructor` refers to `SomeFn`. I actually don't see a reason why one would do something like this, but if anyone has an idea, please let me know.

In the second case, it will be assigned to `obj.SomeVariable`, since `this` refers to the newly created object and is assigned to `obj`.

Comment: Wow, I wrote the answer a year ago... :D If it helped you please mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark next to it.